# can't import enchant using a Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pyenchant

I running Python 2.7  . I'm on OSX Yosemite.

I just installed `pyenchant` via:

`pip install enchant` as per [the instructions](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html).

On the terminal, I can import the module and run the example.

On a Jupyter notebook, I can't import the module:

`ImportError: No module named enchant`

Is there anything I can do in order to run this library via Jupyter notebook? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed conda to manage your environments? Did you launch the notebook and install enchant in the same environment?

Comment: Not really messing around with virtual envs or anything...just wanted a vanilla install. Maybe I can't get away with that and will need to set up an environment. Not using conda...

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck Did you restart kernel after installing enchant?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck It's really wired, I have test this module in ubuntu16.04 with python3.6 and jupyter notebook. I can import it even without restarting kernel. Maybe this is a problem about module path. You can use `enchant.__file__` to check the path in terminal and figure out is it a standard path.

Comment: I'm using Yosemite, I should add (and did add). I'll check out your suggestion.